# AWS Amplify Auth with only social

Tags: aws-amplify

Is it possible to configure AWS Amplify Auth for **only** a social [federated] login?

I've not found a way, and when I try I get the following obvious message that you can't and must have a 'standard' username/email/phone number option.

`Login requires one of the following login mechanisms: email, phone number, or username.`

Answer (score 0):

You can add social login when you are creating your cognito, and you can uncheck the field of userPool on `Edit Hosted UI` from app-client, so only the social login is allowed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwViM.png)